# Batch file to restart an exe on two conditions?

Tags: batch-file

Currently, I have a very simple batch file

```
:loop
start app.exe | set /P "="
goto loop
```

which works fine for restarting the exe every time it closes, however, I'd also like to be able to have the exe restart every 5 minutes in addition to restarting when closed. Any solution?

Comment: Insert a `timeout /T 300` command before the `goto loop` line...

Comment: hi, yes I understand that this would restart the exe every 5 minutes, but my problem is that my exe will close at random intervals of time between 60-120 seconds. I want the batch file to restart upon close, and also to restart in 5 minutes if it has not closed. To my understanding, this would only ensure a restart every 5 minutes and therefore there would be some downtime if say the exe closed at 60s.

Answer (score 0):

## Sleep/Wait In Batch

Sleeping or waiting in batch is a big problem since the beginning of `MS-DOS`. Thousand of threads have talked about methods. So, I'd collect some more accessible methods.

---

#### `TIMEOUT.EXE`

This program has been included in standard Windows since Windows 7. It can also be found in some of the resource packs. Here's is a sample:

```
timeout /t 300
```

which waits **in a random period of 299~300** seconds. The `/t` can be removed optionally.

A `/nobreak` flag is available. When it is not specified, pressing any keys will skip the wait. With this flag, only pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will skip the wait.

---

#### `PING.EXE`

Also included on most Windows NT systems. This program uses a hack to wait even for milliseconds.

```
ping -n 1 -w 300000 1.1>nul
```

This trick may fail due to disconnected network. If the computer is disconnected, it will throw an error. There is also a method to wait for seconds, not millisecond.

---